# Installing Composer on Windows 10 Again?

Tags: windows, composer-php

Has anyone come across this issue.

This will be the 3rd time I am looking to install composer on my windows 10 machine.

I have done this twice before using the global option for all users and using MAMP Pro for the php path.

Twice I have had it up and running ok.

However if I don't use it for a period of time and then try and run composer in the terminal it tells me it isn't a recognised command! I can still see it installed as an app but it is not being recognised in the command line. As I say this is the 3rd time this has happened.

So trying to install it again I get the same error message as I always get that the openssl extension is not installed. Again this is a mystery as this is always enabled in the php.ini and was something I fixed previously when I installed it the first time.

Any ideas of what might be happening here? Windows updates messing up the instalation? I'm getting pretty fed up with going through the same process everytime I want to use it when I know it was installed and working.

Comment: What do you mean by "installed as an app"? How exactly did you do that?

Comment: That's what windows 10 calls your programmes now. If you install anything it sits under your Apps & Features! Just the same as a programme as far as I can see. Anyway installed it with the composer installer as per composer recommends.